# How to create a Flow chart? Javascript or Flash?

Tags: javascript, flash, graph, nodes

I want to create a simple graph as this screeshot :

: [alt text http://s6.imagestime.com/out.php/i417041_grapha.jpg](http://s6.imagestime.com/out.php/i417041_grapha.jpg)
the nodes must be clickablea nd they must have various forms. the arcs must have various colours and arrows!
I found this javascript library :[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html) 
but I can't write into the nodes.

Can anybody help me to find a library, javascript or flash, that create a sample graph as the screenshot? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RaVis](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis) in Flash. Watch a [demo here](http://birdeye.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ravis/RaVisExamples/example-binaries/RaVisExplorer.html)

Comment: Very cool....I have to develop a web-app, then the graph is dynamic. Can I create a graph dynamically?

Comment: By dynamically you mean programmatically, right? Yeah, you can use xml to describe the graph and create it.